# Listwise evaluation of piecewise functions

Tags: list-manipulation, piecewise

I want to create a list of values from a piecewise function evaluated at points in a list.  Is there a way to do this without using loops?

For example

```
z2 = Piecewise[{{x + y^2,x>3}},0]
z = z2/.{x->{1,2,3,4,5}, y->{4,6,3,1,2}}
```

I would like this to return

```
{0,0,0,5,9}
```

i.e.

```
{0,0,0,4 + 1^2, 5 + 2^2}.
```

If the function is not `Piecewise` this works as I expected (want).

I know I can loop over all the lists to do this, but I would like a more elegant solution if one exists.

Comment: Is this acceptable? `z2[{x_, y_}] = Piecewise[{{x+y^2, x>3}}, 0];
z2/@Transpose[{{1,2,3,4,5},{4,6,3,1,2}}]]` which gives you `{0, 0, 0, 5, 9}`

Comment: Thanks Bill that worked.  I went with the other option because I am using the function z2 for other things in the same notebook, and not having to make it explicit in x and y was useful (not that I mentioned that in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MapThread`

```
MapThread[Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[z2]], {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 5, 9}

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** No need to use `MapThread` or `Thread` if you make a [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) function from your `z2` since, then, the function is *automatically threaded over lists that appear as its arguments*.

```
Function[{x, y}, Evaluate @ z2, Listable][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 5, 9}

Alternatively, convert `z2` to a function that is already `Listable`:

```
Simplify`PWToUnitStep[z2] /. {x -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},   y -> {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}}
```

{0, 0, 0, 5, 9}

or

```
Function[{x, y}, Evaluate@Simplify`PWToUnitStep[z2]][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 5, 9}

**Original answer:**

```
z = z2 /. Thread[Thread /@ {x -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, y -> {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 5, 9}

Alternatively, define a function `pw`

```
pw = Piecewise[{{# + #2^2, # > 3}}, 0] &; (* or *)
pw = {x, y} \[Function] Piecewise[{{x + y^2, x > 3}}, 0];
```

and use it is as

```
pw @@@ Thread[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}}] (* or *)
Thread[Unevaluated[pw[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}]]]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 5, 9}

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it works with the equivalent HeavisideTheta version, but not Piecewise.

```
z2 = HeavisideTheta[x - 3] (x + y^2)

z2 /. {x -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, y -> {4, 6, 3, 1, 2}} /. HeavisideTheta[0] -> 0
(*{0, 0, 0, 5, 9}*)
```

Normally `HeavisideTheta[0]` is undefined, presumably so you can choose its behavior yourself, and in this case we need it to be zero. For the current case of x integers, we could have used `UnitStep[x-4]` without the extra Replace specification.